# The Code works right but there is something wrong

Tags: python, eval, nonetype

This is my code, when I run it gives me the right answer but also it gives me 'None':

My Code:

```
def art() :
    a = input('enter a values')
    b = eval(a)

    print(b)    
print(art())
```

Output:

```
enter a values3 + 4
7
None
```

Does anyone know why is that and how to remove it? Thank you.

Comment: Classic: `print()` is not `return`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. Can you explain?